# Cannot find SoapException error code in c#

Tags: c#, exception, reporting-services, soapexception

I am trying to catch specific SoapExceptions but cannot find a error code to use.

I have tried getting the error code using;

```
 catch(SoapException e)
        {
            // Get error code
            int ErrorCode = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode(); //System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(e);

            switch (ErrorCode)
            {
                case -2146233087:
                    {
                        // Default parameters have not been established in the report
                        return "false";
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        return "false";
                    }
            }
        }
```

But this does not work. Does anyone know where to look for the error code?
The only soloution I can possible think of is doing a string match on

```
e.GetBaseException().ToString()
```

but that would be ugly

**ANSWER**

```
string ErrorCode = ((e.Detail).FirstChild).InnerText;
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.code.aspx

Comment: You should enter that as the answer and mark it accepted so that others can find it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string ErrorCode = ((e.Detail).FirstChild).InnerText;
```

returned "rsAccessDenied" which is what I needed to evaluate my error.